# A GAP code for a class of small groups

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I need a GAP code for checking the following question

Let $n$ be a given positive integer. Is it true that every group $G$ of order $n$ is **either** solvable **or** satisfies the condition:
"For any positive divisor $d$ of $n$  there exists a subgroup of $G$ with order $d$ or $n/d$"?

We know that all $n<240$ satisfy the above property. So, the first interested number is $n=240$. Indeed, we are looking for a natural number **$n$ which does not have the above property**.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following brute force code answers your question:

```
nmax:=240;   
for n in [240..nmax] do
     if IsPrime(n) then continue; fi;    
     div:=DivisorsInt(n);    
     gl:=AllSmallGroups(n);    
     for g in gl do    
          if IsSolvableGroup(g) then continue; fi;         
          ll:=LatticeSubgroups(g);    
          cc:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(ll);    
          szs:=List(cc,c->Size(Representative(c)));    
          if not ForAll(div, d->d in szs or n/d in szs) then 
                  Display(IdSmallGroup(g)); 
          fi;    
      od;    
od;
```

It is possible to add a break statement after the Display if only one example is wanted.

---

UPDATE:

There seems to be an exception : The group PSL(2,8) is not solvable and lacks subgroups of order $12, 21, 24, 28, 36, 42, 63, 72, 84, 126, 168, 252$. The question that rises now is :"Could one have predicted this result on theoretical grounds?".

Comment: Dear Nimda, many thanks for your answer. Since I'm not familiar to the GAP, would you tell me: 1. Is the second od; necessary at the end 2. what is the break statement after the Display, exactly? 3. Did you run it for n=240 (true or false)?

Comment: There are as many od's as there are do (it's like brackets closing). If the break is encountered the program halts, so you have your result immediately without waiting the end of the program.

Comment: Yes I tested it and there were no counterexamples. I also run it for solvable groups to see if the test really works and the group SmallGroup(240, 191) came out with no subgroups of order $6$.

Comment: It would interest me to know if you could find a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks! Please also note that there are several ways to improve this: 1. Call `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g)` without the lattice of subgroups since we're not interested in inclusions. 2. Use `SmallGroup(m,n)` instead of generating full list of groups of a given order. 3. Don't test groups for which solvability follows from their order, like $p$-groups and groups of odd order. 4. Have a modular code with three layers: test one group; test all groups of a given order; test all groups from a range of orders. It's a common search problem, and it will be easy to plug different functions there.

Comment: P.S. Perhaps (3) from my remark is not applied here since we want to check that it's **either** solvable or satisfies that condition. I think I was mislead by `if solvable then contunue' part in the code. The OP seems to be interested in checking also that if the group **IS** solvable, then the condition fails. Anyhow, the rest remains valid.

Comment: Dear   Alexander Konovalov, Nimda. Many thanks for your time. May I know the improved code (I can not run it, even for n=240)?

Comment: Hmm, and what's wrong with the current code - for me, it took just several seconds.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I was a bit confused as I understood that, because the construct "either ... or" was used , there was an exclusive or in the sence that if the group was solvable there is no problem and if it isn't it satisfies the property.

Comment: When you run the above code, then you should see true or false, isn't it? Is the answer true for 240?                              p.s.  A group may has the both (solvable & the property)

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand If the code finds a group that is not solvable and  does not possess the given property it displays the groups identity so that you can look it up afterwards. This means that there is a false. If on the other hand there is no group displayed there is a true (but only valid for the range of orders you tested).

Comment: OK. Thanks again!

Comment: ! Interesting ! The first answer is [ 504, 156 ]. 504 is the given number $n$, what is 156?

Comment: Use the GAP command G:=SmallGroup(504,156);StructureDescription(G); and you will get a fair description of the group.

Comment: @Nimda: same for me - first I assumed that if it's solvable, there is no need to check. Anyhow, the code may be easily adjusted for that, so we may leave this as an exercise to the reader. Now we know that $n=504$ does not have a property in question - perhaps worth to update the answer with `SmallGroup(504,156)`

Comment: Regarding to the answer from GAP, can we say there is only one group  of order 504 (i.e. PSL(2,8)) which does not have the property?

Comment: One insolvable, yes.

Comment: If you want to see the result for all the groups of order $504$ put an # before the line $\mathtt{if\ IsSolvableGroup(g)}$.